# ILI9341 pinout problem

Tags: lcd, parallel, tft, 8080, ili9341

I recently ordered a LCD TFT 3.2 inch touch display from aliexpress:
[ILI9341_3.2_TFT_LCD](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-2-inch-TFT-LCD-Touch-Screen-Module-Display-Ultra-HD-320X240-ILI9341-for-3-2/32808968215.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.WBzpvK)

I'm currently going through documentation for the chip ([ILI9341_documentation](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf)) and I can't "connect" all the pins on the pcb of the display to the pins on the chip in documentation.

My plan is to use 16 bit parallel interface, but pins IM0, IM1, IM2, IM3 are not accesabe as it seems, so I am not sure if to use **8080 I** or **8080 II** for 16-bit protocol or if I can even use 16 bit parallel.

**Q1: What protocol is to be used?**

I understand that pins DB[15:0] are for the 16 bit parralel data, top 6 pins are SPI, BL is backlight, RST = reset, WR = WRX, RD = RDX, CS = CSX,

**Q2: so is RS = D/CX?**

**Q3: What is SDCS?**

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I found a datasheet...hard to find, they hide them deep
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HrhsoeIuBADP5YHDu5RRAZ5wvXFfarQ8

Answer (score 1):

Since IM pins are not exposed , we can use only 16bit interface mode.
I tried keeping the configurations for above LCD with 16bit paralled interface and 8080-I protocol, and it worked fine!
Ans 2 -Yes D/CX = RS pin
Ans 3: SDCS is SD card chip select pin.
For pin connection I found some Holy person sharing it on [drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iIsD1AUEXH0RAF2F9mSVLowle0hhAWI3?usp=sharing) along with stm32 fsmc 16bit source code.